# How can I add a printer valid access code to a printer in a batch file?

Tags: printing, batch-file, vbscript, printers

I've got this so far:

```
Cscript %WINDIR%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\Prnport.vbs -a -r IP_192.168.1.78 -h 192.168.1.78
Cscript %WINDIR%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\Prndrvr.vbs -a -m "RICOH Aficio MP C5501 PCL 6" -h %CD% -i %CD%\OEMSETUP.INF
pause
Cscript %WINDIR%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\Prnmngr.vbs -a -p "Ricoh Aficio MP C5501" -m "RICOH Aficio MP C5501 PCL 6" -r IP_192.168.1.78
pause
```

The pauses are just for me to be sure everything is working right. The problem is, the printer has one of those valid access codes. I'm trying to automate the entire process, but I am having trouble adding the valid access code. Is there even a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!

So what you need to do is export printer settings from one that has already been set up.

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Ss /n "Ricoh Aficio MP C5501" /a "settings.dat"
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Sr /n "Ricoh Aficio MP C5501" /a "settings.dat"
```

So I ran the first line after setting up the printer. It gave me the .dat file. I can use that file on all the printers for this one office. I just appended the second line to the end of my code above, and voila! It works!